# How to add missing migrations for Identity? (Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetRoles')

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

[image: Error]

I have created an asp.net application and on my development machine it created these built in tables which is necessary to use the identity part in asp.net mvc.

However, after the initial create when I had to create an `SwitchToIdentityDbContext` migration which had all the logic to create these tables. But in my application at the time, these tables did already exist so I removed that logic. After that (I think) it resulted in the missing tables for identity when I try to deploy my application to a new datasource that does not have these tables.

Is there a way to generate the missing migrations in order to get this running?

As of now, I have this in my config:

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
```

Even if I remove that migration and add a new one, it's empty.

Comment: Maybe u miss a DatabaseInitilalizer for ur DbContext. for example like MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion

Comment: One option is to manually delete all of your migration `.cs` files in Visual Studio, and all records in your migrations db table. You can then create a new migration in Visual Studio that will re-create everything. You may have to completely obliterate the existing db and not just the migrations table, however.

Comment: I would suggest either Drew's option or you generate a complete rebuild script. You could comment out objects that exist if needed: update-database -Script  –SourceMigration $InitialDatabase

Comment: @DrewKennedy your solution did work best, if you can write it as an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care for the data residing in your database, one option to correct the schema is to delete all your `.cs` migrations in Visual Studio and all records in your `dbo.__MigrationHistory` table in your database. After that you can try to create a brand new migration in Visual Studio to fix the database.

However if that doesn't work, you can clear all your migrations in Visual Studio and completely obliterate the database. Then run

`add-migration CreateMyDb`, then `update-database`

and you should be good to go.

If you *do* care for your data, you can always export the contents of your database tables to .csv files in `Server Management Studio` (if you use it) before destroying the migrations.